# The (4*4) array is getting printed twice in the following program. Why?

Tags: c, multidimensional-array, puzzle

This is the [15 puzzle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/15_puzzle) that I'm programming with the initial configuration already given to us. Here, I have considered the hole as the number 0.

I don't get why is the array getting printed twice after pressing the arrow keys. I print the array first, then I make it undergo the required changes depending upon the arrow key entered, and finally if the resulting array is not done in the ascending order, I repeat the steps. But according to this, it should have been printed only once. So what is the problem?

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
void print(int x[][4],int,int);
void func(int z[][4],int*,int,int*,int);
void main()
{
    int a[4][4]={1,  4,15, 7,
                 8, 10, 2,11,
                 14, 3, 6,13,
                 12, 9, 5, 0 };
    int b[4][4];
    int n,temp,i,j,x_coord=3,y_coord=3,count=0;

    while(count!=15)
    {
        print(a,4,4);
        count=0;

        n=getch();
        if(n=='H')
        {
            if(x_coord!=3)
                func(a,&x_coord,1,&y_coord,0);
            else
                printf("\nWrong move!\n");
        }
        if(n=='P')
        {
            if(x_coord!=0)
                func(a,&x_coord,-1,&y_coord,0);
            else
                printf("\nWrong move!\n");
        }
        if(n=='K')
        {
            if(y_coord!=3)
                func(a,&x_coord,0,&y_coord,1);
            else
                printf("\nWrong move!\n");  
        }
        if(n=='M')
        {
            if(y_coord!=0)
                func(a,&x_coord,0,&y_coord,-1);
            else
                printf("\nWrong move!\n");
        }
        for(i=0;i<4;i++)
        {
            for(j=0;j<4;j++)
            {
                b[i][j]=a[i][j];
            }
        }
        for(i=0;i<4;i++)
        {
            for(j=0;j<4;j++)
            {
                if(b[i][j]==0)
                {
                    temp=b[i][j];
                    b[i][j]=b[3][3];
                    b[3][3]=temp;
                }
            }
        }
        for(i=0;i<4;i++)
        {
            for(j=0;j<4;j++)
            {
                if(i==4&&j==4)
                    continue;
                if(b[i][j]==4*i+j+1)
                    count++;
            }
        }
    }
}

void print(int x[][4],int r,int c)
{
    int i,j;
    for(i=0;i<r;i++)
    {
        for(j=0;j<c;j++)
            printf("%d      ",x[i][j]);
        printf("\n\n");
    }
}

void func(int z[][4],int *x,int x1,int *y,int y1)
{
    z[*x][*y]=z[*x+x1][*y+y1];
    z[*x+x1][*y+y1]=0;
    *x=*x+x1;
    *y=*y+y1;
}
```

Comment: `ENTER` maybe? just guessing, didn't read the code.

Comment: https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/

Comment: Side note unrelated to the question: the signature of the main function should not be `void main()`, but rather `int main(void)`.

Comment: Apply consistent indentation. That will help you to analyse the logical structure. Use that to change your several `if`s into a complete `if` `else if` `else`structure. In the last `else` ouput an "unexpected input" and output that input. Apart from that, apply the useful hints in the link I provided above.

Comment: `if(i==4&&j==4)` cannot be true in the `for` loops with `i < 4` and `j < 4`.

Comment: `getch` is not a standard C function. You are checking `if(n=='H')`, do you think the arrow key is the `H` key?

Comment: Try to see what`getch` retruns on your keyboard when you press a key. For example, on my keyboard, up arrow key returns : 'O and H. That is why your array is printed two times.`int main() { int n; while (1) { n = getch(); printf ("Char %c\n",n); } }`